# At what level I should place config classes, beans, filters of Spring Security (java config)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

At what level I should place config classes, beans, filters and the rest that will work directly with Spring Security (java config)? Should I place all at different levels, or can I place all at the same level (eg. Configuration level)?

Comment: what du you mean with "levels" ... pls explain...!

Comment: `@Configuration, @Service ...`